# Should I rephrase this sentence?

Tags: parsing

> Sun always rises, and it always rises from the East.

This is what I’m trying to convey.

> Sun always rises from the East.

Can I just say like this, or should I rephrase it under the consideration that listeners don’t know Sun always rises?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse".  That word means "do grammatical analysis".  I don't think you are using "parse" correctly.  What do you mean "listeners don't know the sun always rises".   Which people don't know this? Is this a **real** problem?  Are you really talking to someone who doesn't know that the sun rises each day?

Comment: @James K Doesn’t “parse” mean “rephrase”? Not really, though, I’m talking to imaginary friends.

Comment: It's always **the sun** and never just **sun** (although **suns** in the plural may refer to solar objects in other systems.)

Comment: not my downvote.  No "parse" doesn't mean "rephrase".  If you mean rephrase, I'll take the liberty of editing  your question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conversations with imaginary friends you can say whatever you want.

You don't need to tell people that the sun rises each day. Idiomatically you can say

> The sun always rises in the east.

Note the article "The", the preposition "in" and the capitalisation "east".

If your imaginary friend doesn't know about the sun, then you might need to have a longer conversation.

> The sun rises every day, and it always rises in the east.